# Running Process listing

Tags: cocoa

Is there any way to list all the processes currently running in Cocoa.I am developing an application in cocoa,which needs to check whether that application is already running or not before launching..Looking for a solution.....

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "all processes"? If you just want to know what applications are running in the user's session, NSWorkspace's launchedApplications is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Apple have a documented route, using some Carbon API. That's [QA1123](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html). There's also [libproc](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-498.1.1/darwin/libproc.h), which is less well-documented but is part of libSystem.